# Customize \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents

How do I copy the format of the image?

My try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centering ÍNDICE}
\usepackage[tocfullflat]{tocstyle}
\usetocstyle{standard}

\begin{document}
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage

\section{ONE}
    \subsection{ONE ONE}
BLA BLA BLA.
    \subsection{ONE TWO}
BLA BLA BLA.
    \subsection{ONE THREE}
BLA BLA BLA.
\section{TWO}
    \subsection{TWO ONE}
BLA BLA BLA.
    \subsection{TWO TWO}
BLA BLA BLA.
    \subsection{TWO THREE}
BLA BLA BLA.
\section{THREE}
    \subsection{THREE ONE}
BLA BLA BLA.
    \subsection{THREE TWO}
BLA BLA BLA.
    \subsection{THREE THREE}
BLA BLA BLA.
\section{FOUR}
    \subsection{FOUR ONE}
BLA BLA BLA.
    \subsection{FOUR TWO}
BLA BLA BLA.
    \subsection{FOUR THREE}
BLA BLA BLA.

\end{document}
```

[image: Image 01]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I see. You want the subsections titles to appear in boldface? I knw how to do that with `titletoc` (a subpackage of `titlesec`). Are you stuck to tocstyle?

Comment: I want this subsubsections in boldface, and the sections with this dots in line.

Comment: What are supposed to be the green rules under the last word of section items?

Comment: Word telling me that it's wrong to put many points after a word :/

Comment: Possible. I tried to reproduce your image. I'll to TeX's default in a moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is that what you want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand*\contentsname{\centering ÍNDICE}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\titlecontents{section}[0em]{\medskip\bfseries}%
{\thecontentslabel.\enspace}%numbered
{}%numberless
{\titlerule*[1.2pc]{.}\contentspage}%
%
\titlecontents{subsection}[0em]{\smallskip}%
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}%numbered
{}%numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.2pc]{.}\contentspage}%
%
\titlecontents{subsubsection}[0em]{\smallskip\bfseries}%
{\thecontentslabel\enspace}%numbered
{}%numberless
{\normalfont\titlerule*[1.2pc]{.}\contentspage}%

\begin{document}

\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\section{ONE}
\subsection{ONE ONE}
\subsubsection{One one one}
\subsubsection{One one two}
\subsubsection*{One one three}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsubsection}{One one three}
BLA BLA BLA.
\subsection{ONE TWO}
BLA BLA BLA.
\subsection{ONE THREE}
BLA BLA BLA.
\section{TWO}
\subsection{TWO ONE}
BLA BLA BLA.
\subsection{TWO TWO}
BLA BLA BLA.
\subsection{TWO THREE}
BLA BLA BLA.
\section{THREE}
\subsection{THREE ONE}
BLA BLA BLA.
\subsection{THREE TWO}
BLA BLA BLA.
\subsection{THREE THREE}
BLA BLA BLA.
\section{FOUR}
\subsection{FOUR ONE}
BLA BLA BLA.
\subsection{FOUR TWO}
BLA BLA BLA.
\subsection{FOUR THREE}
BLA BLA BLA.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I changed the spacing between dots to 1 pc. Is that better?

Comment: Almost.I just need to put the points connecting \section to the page number and a dot after number, like (2. TWO), sir.

Comment: Updated. In my opinion, the dots connecting section ttitles to page numbers make the toc very heavy, typographically speaking. They're supposed to be here to help finding the page numbers, and not very useful for sections, as their page numbers are in boldface.

Comment: I also agree with your opinion, an index "cleaner" and well structured in levels would be much more elegant. But unfortunately, I must follow the standards proposed by my University. Anyway, thank you for your patience and help sir Bernard!